# Check if constant is defined at runtime in Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos

To, for example, access variables in a `NSDictionary` Cocoa frameworks often define keys, such as `UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey`. How can I check if a key is defined at runtime? I found examples on how to check for classes and functions, but not for constants.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Jasarien's answer is roughly correct, but is prone to issues under LLVM 1.5 where the compiler will optimise the if-statement away.

You should also be comparing the address of the constant to `NULL`, rather than `nil` (`nil` has different semantics).

A more accurate solution is this:

```
BOOL isKeyboardBoundsKeyAvailable = (&UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey != NULL);
if (isKeyboardBoundsKeyAvailable) {
  // UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey defined
}
```

Comment: Why not using `#ifdef`?

Comment: @lulian #ifdef works with #define'd macros https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html besides OP asked for a runtime check, which #ifdef won't do.

Answer (score 30):

Check it's pointer against nil, like this

```
if (&UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey != nil)
{
    //Key exists
}
```

Comment: I've added an answer with a correction which might be of interest.

Comment: Why not just `if (&UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey) {}` ?