# Is there any way to detect supported options in SDK

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

“**Using SDK-Based Development**” explains how to use weakly linked classes, methods, and functions ...

I have used this e.g.

```
if ([NSByteCountFormatter class]) {
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to detect supported options e.g.

```
NSRegularExpressionSearch
The search string is treated as an ICU-compatible regular expression.
If set, no other options can apply except NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and NSAnchoredSearch.
You can use this option only with the rangeOfString:... methods and stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:.

Available in OS X v10.7 and later.
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing whether a class, e.g. `NSUserNotificationCenter`, exists, do

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"NSUserNotificationCenter"))
{
    //...
}
```

For testing whether a constant, e.g. NSWindowDidChangeBackingPropertiesNotification, exists, do

```
BOOL NSWindowDidChangeBackingPropertiesNotificationIsAvailable = (&NSWindowDidChangeBackingPropertiesNotification != NULL);
if (NSWindowDidChangeBackingPropertiesNotificationIsAvailable) 
{
    //...
}
```

Check out this answer also: [Check if constant is defined at runtime in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122177/check-if-constant-is-defined-at-runtime-in-obj-c/5268545#5268545)

In your case, this looks like

```
BOOL NSRegularExpressionSearchIsAvailable = (&NSRegularExpressionSearch != NULL);
if (NSRegularExpressionSearchIsAvailable)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This may work with NSWindowDidChangeBackingPropertiesNotification which is defined as APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSWindowDidExitVersionBrowserNotification, so you can take its address.

NSRegularExpressionSearch is defined in NSString.h as NSRegularExpressionSearch NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 3_2) = 1024
So you can't take its address, and would be converted at compile time.